# Tridion - Create a "copy" of selected publications into a separate recreation of the DB

Tags: tridion

Does there exist a piece of software that can extract a set of publications and associated items, etc from the DB and re-create them in a separate DB?

My DB is 203 GB and contains hundreds of pubs; now I only really want to work with a handful of pubs within this quagmire.  Deleting everything is taking an absolute age, mostly down to the poor performance of the SQL box that I'm running on (cannot be changed)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps I am missing something here, but can you not just make an export with Content Porter of the Publications you want. Then create a new tridion_cm database with the database manager, hook up you CMS to the new DB and import the items into the new system?

Comment: I've tried using the CP with no luck.  It created the structure fine, but exhibited strange behaviour during use (random missing data, partially copied schemas, etc) - the CP is something I inherently distrust, so would prefer to do it with a little ASP.NET app which links to a custom SP.  I could probably do it myself but think it requires a knowledge of the Tridion DB that I simply don't have at this time, nor do I have the time to dedicate to.  It may well be a case of living with the poor performance (but it can take, for example, 10 seconds to open a structure group)

Comment: 10 seconds to open a SG sounds pretty scary - I suggest you follow @JRW's comments below. It sounds like you have bigger issues than volume of content. I would also avoid writing your own tool, CP has thousands of developer and tester hours behind it for a good reason. If CP is not working as it should, it may be a bug that Customer Support can help you with. It really should be able to do what you need if you can get your data to a valid form (i.e. fill in all mandatory fields etc).

Comment: Hi Martin, I think it would be best to try and figure out some of the porting issues you have (usually Component XML not matching to Schema XSDs).  You can try and work around it now, but this will come back and get you again at some point the future.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the comment.  I think it's too far gone to rectify porting issues in any sensible timeframe, as I am dealing with the /entire/ production DB (+ another 80 pubs) which we now have replicated onto a dev server.  I essentially want to isolate down to the new 80 pubs and remove the rest, but with 300 pubs with 1.5m components sharing everything deriving from a level-2/3 blueprint... it's not fun.  I've given up on this due to time restrictions and managed to get the DB and CM machines scheduled to be moved onto a SAN from a single disk which should improve performance no end.

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer to your immediate question, but if you haven't done so already, using the Purge Tool to remove older versions of content, etc. from the DB will improve performance.

Having good, regular DB maintenance (reindex, stats) will also improve performance.
Options to look into:

Fullscan with statistics
Truncating the SQL log for the DB (not the Tridion log DB)
Clearing records from the Tridion log DB